# Linq To SQL : Error "Database node not found"

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am attempting to experiment with linq to sql using [this site](http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/10/14/achieving-poco-s-in-linq-to-sql.html) as a guide.

When running a test I keep getting an error parsing the mapping file I created. The error:

System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException : Database node not found.  Is the mapping namespace (http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/mapping/2007) correctly specified?

Here is the mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Database Name="Test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/mapping/2007">
      <Table Name="dbo.Categories" Member="Category">
        <Type Name="Category">
          <Column Name="ID" Member="ID" Storage="id" DbType="Char(32) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" IsPrimaryKey="true" />
          <Column Name="ParentID" Member="ParentID" Storage="parentID" DbType="Char(32)" />
          <Column Name="Name" Member="Name" Storage="name" DbType="VarChar(50) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
        </Type>
      </Table>
    </Database>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

the line:

```
<Table Name="dbo.Categories" Member="Category">
```

Needed changed to:

```
<Table Name="dbo.Categories" Member="Categories">
```

and now its working.